# Google spreadsheet: importxml xpath no works

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

why xpath does not work on some sites like economiaoggi.it?
I did various tests but google does not pull me nothing compared to other sites

Comment: Share more details including `XPath` expressions you've tried already

Comment: `//div[@id='breadcrumbs']` works for me..